# Is it possible to define implicit casting behavior of primitive types? C++

Tags: c++, casting

Can the user define how primitives cast between primitives? Or how they cast *to* user-defined types? ("Implicit casting constructor"? yikes)

This is a hypothetical question and it's hard to imagine a usage but perhaps one might want to affect how ints cast to bool.

Comment: What exactly is your problem is the converting constructor?

Comment: Well I was thinking not of assignment but something really wacky like
  5.doSomething();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't change how built-in types behave. You're not allowed to break the language like that, much like you cannot overload a new `operator+` for `int`s that does something else.

The language needs to be able to make certain basic guarantees so that libraries can be written that can rely on basic behaviour!

You can convert any type *to* a user-defined type by providing a constructor that's callable with one argument, e.g.:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(T const &);
    // ...
};
```

Now you can say, `T x; Foo y = x;` etc.

You can also do the reverse and provide conversions *from* your class:

```
struct Foo
{
    operator S() const;
    // ...
};
```

Now you can also say, `S s = y;`.

Comment: You can also create new types of casts, e.g. `checked_cast`, and use those.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change how primitives cast to other primitives.
You can define how user defined types can be cast to primitive types/any type by providing a **[conversion constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2ff0fz8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the user define how primitives cast between primitives?

No. The language is not mutable.

> Or how they cast to user-defined types? ("Implicit casting constructor"? yikes)

Yes:

```
struct X {
    X() {}
    X(int a) {} // implicit cast
};

X x;
x = 10; // int implicitly cast to X
```